# How can I patch dev & test servers with a subscriptions which covers only production servers?

Tags: linux, redhat, spacewalk, subscription

Our organization purchased a RedHat platinum support subscription five years ago, and use it for all prod, dev, and test systems. After a recent organizational change, our management decided not to pay platinum support other than for production systems, to reduce costs.

Being a system administrator, I was using satellite servers to patch all the dev, test, and prod systems. Since management have decided not to renew the subscription, how can I patch the RedHat dev and test systems? Can I still use the satellite servers to push the RedHat patches to dev and test environments?

Also, I’m aware that I don’t get support from RedHat for dev and test servers, but can I still update and patch the dev and test servers using the satellite where we have subscription for prod systems already? I’m planning to apply those patches to dev and test systems.

Is there any other way I can patch the test and dev systems?

Comment: Legally, you cannot

Comment: is they any other way i can patch all redhat DEV/Test servers ?

Answer (score 2):

After lots of work and research, I've finally implemented spacewalk. 
Technically I've installed a redhat system and registered to rhn network. Once after I registered ingot the pki ssl certs. 
I've exported those certificate to spacewalk and successfully synced all the respective redhat channels.

Now all my redhat systems are registered to spacewalk and doing the patching via spacewalk.